# Android SQLite Creating Table Error

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to create some tables for my android application but am running into some trouble with the tables creations. I have one dDBAdapter that is holding all me creates. The first table creates fine but I cannot see why it is failing on the second one.

Any help will be great but I am sure I have just over looked something small

**Table Create Code**

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_RECIPES = "create table if not exists recipes(" +
        "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        "name VARCHAR," +
        "ingredents TEXT," +
        "instructions TEXT," +
        "description TEXT," +
        "time TIME)";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_SHOPPING_LIST = "create table if not exists shopping_list(" +
        "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
        "name TEXT," +
        "quantity FLOAT)";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_PUBLIC_DB = "create table if not exists public_db(" +
        "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
        "name TEXT," +
        "number INT)";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_CURRENT_CONTENTS = "create table if not exists current_contents(" +
        "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
        "name TEXT," +
        "quantity FLOAT," +
        "expiry DATE)";
```

**Error**

```
18:41:35.778 27198-27198/? E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "AUTOINCREMENTname": syntax error
10-13 18:41:35.787 27198-27198/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-13 18:41:35.787 27198-27198/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: app.rory.menu, PID: 27198
10-13 18:41:35.787 27198-27198/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{app.rory.menu/app.rory.pocket_chef.MyActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "AUTOINCREMENTname": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create table if not exists shopping_list(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENTname TEXT,quantity FLOAT)
10-13 18:41:35.787 27198-27198/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
10-13 18:41:35.787 27198-27198/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
10-13 18:41:35.787 27198-27198/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
10-13 18:41:35.787 27198-27198/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
10-13 18:41:35.787 27198-27198/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-13 18:41:35.787 27198-27198/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
10-13 18:41:35.787 27198-27198/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
10-13 18:41:35.787 27198-27198/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-13 18:41:35.787 27198-27198/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-13 18:41:35.787 27198-27198/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
10-13 18:41:35.787 27198-27198/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
10-13 18:41:35.787 27198-27198/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "AUTOINCREMENTname": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create table if not exists shopping_list(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENTname TEXT,quantity FLOAT)
10-13 18:41:35.787 27198-27198/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
10-13 18:41:35.787 27198-27198/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
10-13 18:41:35.787 27198-27198/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
10-13 18:41:35.787 27198-27198/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
10-13 18:41:35.787 27198-27198/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
10-13 18:41:35.787 27198-27198/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
10-13 18:41:35.787 27198-27198/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1674)
10-13 18:41:35.787 27198-27198/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1605)
10-13 18:41:35.787 27198-27198/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at app.rory.pocket_chef.Adapters.DBAdapter$DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DBAdapter.java:68)
10-13 18:41:35.787 27198-27198/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
10-13 18:41:35.787 27198-27198/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
10-13 18:41:35.787 27198-27198/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at app.rory.pocket_chef.Adapters.DBAdapter.open(DBAdapter.java:89)
10-13 18:41:35.787 27198-27198/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at app.rory.pocket_chef.Fragments.recipes_Fragment.onActivityCreated(recipes_Fragment.java:42)
10-13 18:41:35.787 27198-27198/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2061)
10-13 18:41:35.787 27198-27198/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:912)
10-13 18:41:35.787 27198-27198/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
10-13 18
```

Comment: uninstall and reinstall your app, after you modified the code.

Comment: I have tried that already and I am still getting the same error

Comment: No. Now you added the comma - which is correct. So you must uninstall and reinstall your app.

Comment: `"AUTOINCREMENTname"` is all you need to know. (that and how SQL db upgrade work in android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just remove `AUTOINCREMENT` from all you sql query.

In SQLite a column declared INTEGER PRIMARY KEY will autoincrement by itself.

check [HERE](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1)